# "Undefined variable: environment" How do I get App::enviroment()?

Tags: php, laravel, environment

//Environment  Laravel Framework 8.49.1

I was trying to make a conditional branch by using the data of App::environment, but I couldn't find a way to get the data. I think that I'm supposed to get local because It's written APP_ENV=local in the `.env` file. Does anyone know how to get App::environment?

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
use App\Models\Dice;
use App\Models\LoadedDice;

$environment = App::environment();

class DiceController extends Controller {

    public function rollDouble(): int {
        // $dice = new Dice();
        // return $dice->roll() + $dice->roll();

        if ($environment == 'local') {
        // if (APP::enviroment('local')) {
            $dice = new LoadedDice();
        } else {
            $dice = new Dice();
        }
        return $dice->roll() + $dice->roll();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Hedayatullah Sarwary Hello! Thank you for your amending! I'd like to ask you one thing. Do I have to put "{"  on the right of classes and functions? I think that "{" is located on the under of classes and functions in Laravel by default.

Comment: I think it is better to put on the right of methods and it is taking less lines and it it cleaner.

Comment: @Hedayatullah Sarwary I totally got it! Thank you!! I'll do it too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you change the 'env' item in the config/app.php file?

By default it looks like this:

```
'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'production'),
```

In other words, when getting the ENV it will check the APP_ENV variable of the .env file, if not defined, it will return 'production'.

I tested the two functions below on Laravel 8 and both returned the value correctly.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
echo App::environment(); //output: local

echo app('env'); //output: local
```

You've probably changed the config/app.php file or have some cache bothering you, try clearing it:

```
php artisan clear-compiled
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan view:clear
```

I believe it should solve... Otherwise, are there any errors in the logs?

---

EDITED: I looked at your code, you are defining the variable outside the class and don't pass it inside at any time.

Put the variable inside the function:

```
class DiceController extends Controller
{

    public function rollDouble(): int
    {

        $environment = App::environment();

        if ($environment == 'local') {
            $dice = new LoadedDice();
        } else {
            $dice = new Dice();
        }

        return $dice->roll() + $dice->roll();
    }
```

Comment: I could see local by putting "$environment  = App::environment()" inside the function! I didn't change anything in the config/app.php file and I thought the defined variable outside the class can be used... Anyway, Thank you very much!

Comment: @Ryotaro you have to learn basic (OOP) PHP before trying to use OOP or a franework... This is very basic for you to mess up...

Comment: @matiaslauriti I know!! I've been studying at a programing school to learn PHP, but I think I'm learning Laravel without learning OOP... So I'll study OOP and so on! Thank you!!! I'll do my best! :)